# Importing csv file in postgres 9.5 need to replace /n with null

Tags: postgresql

I want to import csv file to a table. The CSV file contains the new line as `\N`.

While copying it saves to my database. So needs to replace that `/n` to NULL while importing through

```
copy tbl_created_doc_no FROM '/Desktop/admin/document_no.csv' (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ';');
```

Can anyone suggest an option for replacing

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> NULL
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N
>   (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV
>   format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases
>   where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This
>   option is not allowed when using binary format.

So if youwant csv format, specify NULL yourself with `NULL '\N'`, example:

```
t=# select * from so78;
                h                 | i
----------------------------------+---
 2e346ec46b4ae31f54bf3ad3d90d3183 | 1
t=#  copy so78 from stdin (delimiter ';', null '\N', format csv);
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> a;\N
>> \.
COPY 1
t=# select * from so78;
                h                 | i
----------------------------------+---
 2e346ec46b4ae31f54bf3ad3d90d3183 | 1
 a                                |
```